# Google Classroom API only access

Tags: google-classroom

Good morning.

I have a ED tech who I would like to give Google Classroom API access to but I don't want to give them any other Admin access. Is this possible with a Custom Admin role somehow?

Comment: If you go form your Admin console on a user and `Admin roles and privileges`, you can select `Create a new Role` and `Select priveleges` - e.g. `Gmail`or `Calendar`, but unfortunately `Classroom` does not seem to be an eligible option.

Comment: I see that and that is why I am asking here.. It would be a bad precedence to set to start allowing people admin access to areas unneeded.

Comment: You can always file a feature request at Google's [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different admin access roles using the pre-defined roles or customize roles here.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986#super_admin